# React install problems with npm

Tags: npm, create-react-app

When I run npx create-react-app, I had these errors. Maybe someone knows whats it's wrong? P.S. also had tried npm-install -g create-react-app.

```
    C:\Users\Deividas\Desktop\PAMEGINIMAS>create-react-app my-app
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:621
  throw e;
  ^

Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise'
    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:9)
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:499:14)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:948:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:854:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\run-async\index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a recent problem with npm. There is an issue open as of the last few hours and it seems like people are working on it. I don't think it's anything to do with yourproject.

[The issue](https://github.com/then/is-promise/issues/13#issuecomment-619401394)

While the issue is being fixed: try installing node version 12.12.0 as shown below (if using nvm) and run create-react-app again.

```
nvm install 12.12.0
nvm use 12.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to clear your cache `npm cache clean --force`. What version of node and npm are you using?

Comment: After npm cache clean --force had the same error.  npm version: 6.13.1; node version: v13.3.0